# Javascript : run submit loading page code after valid form

Tags: javascript, validation

i use this code when submit form show loading page icon my problem with validator if submit form and some fields is empty or not currect the code is show lodaing page for infinity ..

any way to run this code after valid form ?

Thx

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("form").submit(function(){

$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
$(this).after("<div class='se-pre-con text-center pp500'><i class='fa fa-<?php  echo $site_icon;  ?> fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw text-color1'></i></div>").fadeIn();  

  });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of validation are you talking about? HTML5 form validation? Something added via a jQuery plugin? …?

Comment: this : https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator

Comment: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-events, _“Conditionally handling the submit event”_

Comment: Its Working Now, Thx